# Android: преобразовать существующий IntentService в Intent

Tags: android, android-service, android-intent

Ситуация такова: открыли приложение, нажали кнопку, запустили IntentService, закрыли приложение, затем оно выгрузилось из памяти. А сервис продолжает висеть. Например, благодаря уведомлению.

Как мне при открытии приложения преобразовать уже существующий IntentService, вместо создания нового? Сам экземпляр существующего сервиса я получить могу, а как его преобразовать в Intent без пересоздания?

```
new Intent(this, SomeService.class)
```

Я так понимаю, в любом случае создает НОВЫЙ сервис. Или я не прав?

Answer (score 1):

Новый сервис не должен создаваться, должен лишь вызваться определённый метод уже существующего сервиса, в чём легко убедиться просто проверив это.